# How to create Context Menu using XML file?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am using XML file for creating Context Menu for my ListView. (Please see below). I also want to set a header for this Context Menu. I read (at http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg43062.html)that I can use menu.setHeaderTitle(myContextMenuTitle) in onCreateContextMenu Method. But I need to set this in XML file. How can I accomplish this?

Following is code for onCreateContextMenu Method, correct me if I am doing anything wrong..
This is my context_menu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/open" android:title="Open"/>
</menu>
```

This is my **onCreateContextMenu** Method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 }
```

This is my **onCreate** Method:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  //  extras = getIntent().getExtras();

  registerForContextMenu(getListView());

  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do it the way you are currently doing it.

Comment: does this mean we can not do it through XML?

Comment: Yes. Only way to do it is via menu.setHeader

Answer (score 18):

You can call `setHeaderTitle("mytitle")` method in ,menu object .
In override method you get menu object as paramrter of `OnCreateContextMenu` method.
like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
   menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.icon);
   menu.setHeaderTitle("Share Menu.");
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

   inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
 }
```