# Change text color of Context Menu item

Tags: android

This is my issue, i want to make the text of item in underline turn to black color, it currently in white, i don't know how to change text color for these item. Could someone help me !

Could you see this picture for clearly my issue : [Images Here !](http://www.upanh.com/slider/?e=malihu&s=upload&start=1rte7l2zfxp) (Focus on red underline item)

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml layout for the Context Menu. The post below might help you.

[How to create Context Menu using XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592160/how-to-create-context-menu-using-xml-file)

Comment: i also create my context menu in xml file, but i don't know how to change color of it. Your link do not change context menu color.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009942/2914140:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```